# how to invoke logout controller in jasig CAS

Tags: jsp, cas, jasig

I am using CAS for my application.i want to change some code in Logout controller.so pls tell me how to invoke log out controller in my application..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The /logout url on the CAS server is the CAS logout : it destroys the SSO session and destroys all application sessions by sending them (to the CAS service url) a CAS logout request.